# Neo4j Import folder shared between services in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I am currently doing an open source project that is a social network and when I am setting up the docker-compose I find myself stuck in a problem.

I have my neo4j service and I have a python service that generates a fake graph for me.
Then i need the import folder of neo4j have the temp folder of fake_graph service in real time.

The service that generates the fake graph works as follows:
For each action block (create users, create friends, ...) first create the datasets in .csv files (in a folder called temp) and then import them into neo4j.

So my problem is how do I ensure that neo4j, in its import folder, receives the files that are being dynamically created in the temp folder of the fake_graph service.

this is my docker-compose code:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Noe4j database config
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j_social_seed_db 
    image: neo4j:5.15.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4jSocial
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_server.memory.pagecache.size=1G
      - NEO4J_server.directories.import=import
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j/data:/data
      - ./neo4j/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - ./fake-graph/app/temp:/import
    networks:
      - net
  # Social Seed Api in Java config
  social-seed-app:
    container_name: app_social_seed
    image: social-seed:0.0.1
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=bolt://neo4j:7687
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=neo4j
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=neo4jSocial
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    networks:
      - net
  # Fake Graph config
  fake-graph:
    container_name: fake_graph_service
    image: python:3.11.2-slim
    build: 
      context: ./fake_graph    
    volumes:
      - ./fake_graph:/app
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    environment:
      - GENERATE_FAKE_GRAPH
      - DATABASE_URI=bolt://neo4j:7687
    command: >
      sh -c "if [ '$GENERATE_FAKE_GRAPH' = 'true' ]; then python /app/generate.py; else sleep infinity; fi"    
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Comment: Have you considered having the Python service simply use the [Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/) API to directly update the database?

Comment: The question is that when you are going to insert the data into neo4j with cypher you have to give it a path in the query for the .csv file and this path has to be local (import path) or by url.

Comment: What I have considered is to have a web server run in my python service that shares the temp folder with me and then from the execution of the query the url of each file is called using the address of the web server.

Comment: But there should be a way to configure services in docker so that a folder in one service points to another folder in another service or some way to do this would be the most conventional I think

Comment: Your overall design seems to be overly complex and incomplete (how do you plan on ingesting the data from the file once you have access to it?). What I am suggesting is that you use a very simple design instead. Just have your Python service use the Driver API to directly execute a query in the neo4j database; you can even use Cypher. No files are needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a long time and doing several tests I found the solution. was to create a shared volume with the bind option pointing to where these folders are referenced. Here I leave the code of my docker-composa file in case someone else runs into this problem.
Greetings

```
version: "3.8"
services:  
  # Noe4j database config
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j_social_seed_db 
    image: neo4j:5.15.0-enterprise
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4jSocial
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_server.memory.pagecache.size=1G
      - NEO4J_server.directories.import=import
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j/data:/data
      - ./neo4j/conf:/conf
      - ./neo4j/logs:/logs
      - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - import_data:/import
    networks:
      - net
  # Social Seed Api in Java config
  social-seed-app:
    container_name: app_social_seed
    image: social-seed:0.0.1
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=bolt://neo4j:7687
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=neo4j
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=neo4jSocial
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    networks:
      - net
  # Fake Graph config
  fake-graph:
    container_name: fake_graph_service
    image: python:3.11.2-slim
    build: 
      context: ./fake_graph    
    volumes:
      - ./fake_graph:/app
      - import_data:/app/temp
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    environment:
      - GENERATE_FAKE_GRAPH
      - DATABASE_URI=bolt://neo4j:7687
    command: >
      sh -c "if [ '$GENERATE_FAKE_GRAPH' = 'true' ]; then python /app/generate.py; else sleep infinity; fi"    
    networks:
      - net
volumes:
  import_data:
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
networks:
  net:
```